# How to use spaces in "for" function

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

The problem is that I'm doing a script for class, and the question is to "Make a script that names all the files in the actual directory and tells us the name and the permissions they have", so I made the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash

for name in `ls -l . | awk {print'$9'}`
do
echo "The file $name has the following permissions: `ls -l . | grep $name | cut -d" " -f1`"
done
```

Okay, the script works somewhat, but the problem is that it won't show all the files in the `ls -l` list because I'm printing the `9th column` (The name of the file) but if it has a space, the word after the space is in `column 10`, so I tried it like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

for name in `ls -l . | awk {print'$9,$10'}`
do
echo "The file $name has the following permissions: `ls -l . | grep $name | cut -d" " -f1`"
done
```

But when I do this, the problem is that the variable $name will reference to the first column and the second column as separate words, and it will show both as if they were different files.

I also tried escaping the spaces in `ls`using `ls -lb`but then the `grep`command won't work, and if I use  `grep '$name\s'` it will copy literally the $name\s so it won't search anything in the `ls`command...

Maybe it's really easy to solve this problem, but I've been over this for more than 5 hours and nothing... Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Don't parse `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)! Instead, use a [glob](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ShellGlobbing):

```
for name in ./*; do
```

There are other ways you can improve the script too.

1. In the loop, again don't parse `ls`. Instead, use `stat` to get the permissions directly.<sup>1</sup>
2. Use the newer command substitution syntax `$(...)` instead of deprecated backticks `` `...` ``
3. Define a variable `$perms` to make the print string a bit cleaner and easier to read.

So:

```
for name in ./*; do
    perms="$(stat -c "%A" "$name")"
    echo "The file $name has the following permissions: $perms"
done
```

Footnotes:

1. If `stat` didn't exist, and you had to get the permissions from `ls`, you would give it the filename as an argument, and use the `-d` flag so it doesn't descend into directories or dereference symlinks.

   ```
   ls -ld "$name" | cut -d" " -f1
   ```

   But again, you shouldn't parse `ls`. This method fails if any of the filenames contain newlines.

Answer (score 8):

It's definitely not a good plan to write things like

```
for stuff in `ls`; ...
```

Parsing the output of `ls` is [a really bad idea](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) because the output of `ls` is just text, and is an unreliable representation of the actual names of your files.

To do things with files **use shell globs** instead.

```
for stuff in *; ...
```

Instead of `*`, you can use `./*` which means the same thing, but is safer because all paths start with `./` (the current directory) instead of whatever suspect symbol your filenames start with, which could be one that causes the shell to perform an expansion (such as `~`) (although you should definitely "quote" your variables to prevent such unwanted shell expansions) or one that the command you are trying to use may try to interpret specially (such as `-`). You can also use `*` and not `./*`, but add `--` after all the options to the commands you run in the loop, to prevent filenames beginning with `-` being interpreted as options. This gives a clean path, but if you want to use `./*` you can sometimes clean the path using `"$(basename $var)"` in commands, or other tricks. Be aware that not all commands support `--` to indicate the end of options.

Rather than trying to parse what you want out of `ls -l`, use a command specifically for displaying file metadata and ask only for the output you want.

```
stat -c "%n %A" file
```

should give you what you want. If you want to display a message, you can just write it in :)

Here's how I'd do this:

```
for file in *; do stat -c 'The permissions of %n are: %A' -- "$file"; done
```

Comment: I like it too much to not add the [GNU `parallel`](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/parallel) way here: `parallel stat -c\"The permissions of %n are: %A\" {} ::: *` This does exactly the same as the `for` loop above, but uses multi-processing and may therefore be more efficient in case of *many* files to process.